# Is there a way to launch readme notes from the end of an installanywhere install?

Tags: installation, installanywhere

Is there a way to launch readme notes from the end of an installanywhere install?

I know in install shield, some times there is a check box for "Run program" or View Readme notes." Can install anywhere do that same thing?

Grae

Answer (score 2):

In Enterprise Edition (I don't have access to a Standard Edition installation), there are a couple of choices.

The first is an Action similar to "Run Program" called "Execute Command." You give it a command line and it executes that command line. This can be any program that is currently installed, including an executable that is included with your installer.

The challenge with "Execute Command" is that if you *are* using InstallAnywhere, then you're probably targeting multiple installation platforms. It's a rare command line that is cross-platform compatible.

An alternative Action is "Launch Default Browser." In this case, you either select a file from your installation (i.e., your readme file), or you type in a URL (maybe you're pulling the readme file from a web site). The indicated file or URL will be loaded into a browser instance when this Action executes.

This Action may also not be cross-platform compatible. When your installation target is a non-GUI *nix platform, a browser may not be available. For instance, it's common for a *nix server to not have X installed, in which case, there won't be a "real" browser (you may have `links`, `linx` or some other text-based browser, but these aren't guaranteed to be available and may not even work with the "Launch Default Browser" Action -- I've never tried them).

So, your best solution is a combination of these two Actions, split by Rules into GUI-mode and Console-mode installation paths.

Start by adding a "Launch Default Browser" Action with a Rule that checks if the current mode is GUI (use "Compare InstallAnywhere Variables" where `$INSTALLER_UI$ equals GUI`). The "Installed File" or "Other URL" will be your readme file.

Next add an "Execute Command" Action with a Rule that checks if the current mode is Console  (same Rule as above, where `$INSTALLER_UI$ equals CONSOLE`). The Command Line value will use the "`more`" command with its argument being the path to your text readme file.

This should get you where you want to go, while still supporting multiple platforms.

FWIW, all of this information is detailed in the InstallAnywhere docs, freely available from this link: http://support.flexerasoftware.com/doc/List.aspx?m=installation&pid=0000000000000019&pn=InstallAnywhere